# "The value of the local variable is not used."

Tags: java, boolean

```
package checkPrime;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckPrime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean isPrime = true;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");   
        int n = scanner.nextInt();

        scanner.close();

        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {

            if (n % i == 0) {

                isPrime = false;

            }

        }

        if (isPrime = false || n == 1) {

            System.out.print(n + " is not prime.");

        } else {

            System.out.print(n + " is prime.");

        }

    }

}
```

So I wrote this program to check if a number is prime and it's working well, but I get this error on the line where the boolean "isPrime" is declared: "The value of the local variable isPrime is not used.". It's not affecting the functionality of my program but I was wondering if there is any way to make it go away.

Comment: Use `==` to compare values; a single `=` is **assignment**. So `if (isPrime = false || n == 1)` is wrong, it must be: `if (isPrime == false || n == 1)` and even better would be: `if (!isPrime || n == 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake here:

```
if (isPrime = false || n == 1) {
```

It should have been:

```
if (isPrime == false || n == 1) {
            ^^
      double equals!
```

The warning occurs because without the double equal sign, you are assigning to `isPrime` instead of comparing it with `false`. If you do that here, then throughout the program, you have only assigned to `isPrime` but never used its value.

By the way, an assignment statement evaluates to the value assigned to it, so `isPrime = false` will always evaluate to `false`. This is also why the compiler did not warn you about using `=`.

Comment: Extra note… To prevent this kind of error, always reverse the test: `false == isPrime`, so that if you accidentally use a single `=` the `false = isPrime` generates a compiler error whereas `isPrime = false` compiles and runs but does not perform as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is wrong - you're assigning `false` to `isPrime` using the `=` operator instead of checking if it's `false` with the `==` operator:

```
if (isPrime == false || n == 1) {
    // Here-^
    System.out.print(n + " is not prime.");
} else {
    System.out.print(n + " is prime.");
}
```

Or, since `isPrime` is a `boolean`, just evaluate it directly:

```
if (!isPrime || n == 1) {
    // Here^
    System.out.print(n + " is not prime.");
} else {
    System.out.print(n + " is prime.");
}
```